# Tutorial for Printer Port Coding

Tags: c, windows, hardware-interface

I want to do hardware interaction using "C" Program. I have heard that using Printer's port I can create a C Program which can control a "Bulb" or "Tube Light" to on or off. Which means if I press any key from my Keyboard ( Suppose "1" ) then Bulb will be on and from another key I want to off it. How can I achieve this ?

Comment: By "printer port" you actually mean a parallel port.  Not many computers actually have parallel ports these days; they've been superseded by USB.

Comment: I am using old Dell laptop , Plantium-2

Comment: @Wyzard: It sounds like he want to bit-bang the parallel port.

Comment: Please say something about your operating system, since direct hardware access is not possible in a platform-neutral way in C.

Comment: I have Win 98  Operating System

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See http://logix4u.net/parallel-port.  Since (you say) you’re using Windows 98, their [Tutorial on Parallel Port Interfacing](http://logix4u.net/parallel-port/15-a-tutorial-on-parallel-port-interfacing) will be directly applicable.

If you want to write programs that can be used on later versions of Windows, see also their [Inpout32.dll for Windows 98/2000/NT/XP](http://logix4u.net/parallel-port/16-inpout32dll-for-windows-982000ntxp), which claims to be compatible with the programs from the book *Parallel Port Complete* (see [the book’s website](http://www.lvr.com/parprtib.htm) for downloadable sample programs).

Another good-looking tutorial/sample for inpout32.dll is at http://www.hytherion.com/beattidp/comput/pport.htm.